# Joining Table Laravel Combined with JQuery and AJAX request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, postgresql

i want to join some of tables and getting the data to display into datatables, i'm recently using yajra datatables.

Here list of tables that i want to join :

1. ekspedisis : `id, client_id, org_id, expedisi_id, expedisi_name, status, created_at, updated_at`
2. clients : `id, client_id, client_name, status, created_at, updated_at`
3. organizations: `id, org_id, org_name, org_address, status, created_at, updated_at`

NOTE : `id just for indexing, AUTO INCREMENT`

So, the problem is, i want to joining all tables above, i want to display client_name and org_name instead of displaying client_id and org_id at datatables. I'm getting error if i'm not using $ekspedisi = Ekspedisi::all() to get the certain data in EkspedisiController.php:

**`DataTables warning: table id=ekspedisis-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`**

***Here's my table.blade.php AT SCRIPT SECTION***

```
@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">

    var table = $('#ekspedisis-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'ekspedisi.json',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'expedisi_id', name: 'expedisi_id' },
            { data: 'client_id', name: 'client_id' },
            { data: 'org_id', name: 'org_id' },
            { data: 'expedisi_name', name: 'expedisi_name' },
            { data: 'status', name: 'status'},
            {
                data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false
            }
        ]
    });


    function deleteEkspedisi(id){
        var popup = confirm("Are you sure for delete this data?");
        var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        if(popup == true){
            $.ajax({
                url     : "{{ url('ekspedisi') }}/"+id,
                type    : "POST",
                data    : { '_method':'DELETE', '_token': csrf_token, 'id':id },
                success : function(data){
                    table.ajax.reload();
                },
                error   : function(){
                    alert('Opps: Something Wrong!');
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
@endpush
```

***EkspedisiController.php***

```
public function json(){

        // $ekspedisi = Ekspedisi::all();
        $ekspedisi = DB::table('ekspedisis')
                     ->join('clients', 'clients.client_id', '=' ,'ekspedisis.client_id')
                     ->join('organizations', 'organizations.org_id', '=', 'ekspedisis.org_id')
                     ->select('ekspedisis.*', 'clients.client_name', 'organizations.org_name') 
                     ->get();

        return Datatables::of($ekspedisi)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
                return '<a href="/ekspedisi/'.$data->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                        <a onclick="deleteEkspedisi('.$data->id.');" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';
            })
            ->editColumn('client_id', function($data){
                return $data->client_name;
            })
            ->editColumn('org_id', function($data){
                return $data->org_name;
            })
            ->make(true);
    }
```

***Ekspedisi.php (MODEL)***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ekspedisi extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ekspedisis';

    protected $fillable = [
        'expedisi_id', 'client_id', 'org_id', 'expedisi_name'
        // , 'status'
    ];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class);
    }
}
```

***Client.php (MODEL)***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clients';

    protected $fillable = [
        'client_id', 'client_name'
        // , 'status'
    ];

    public function ekspedisi()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ekspedisi::class);
    }
}
```

***Organization.php (MODEL)***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Organization extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'organizations';

    protected $fillable = [
        'org_id', 'org_name', 'org_address'
    ];

    public function ekspedisi()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ekspedisi::class);
    }
}
```

***web.php (ROUTES)***

```
...
Route::resource('ekspedisi', 'EkspedisiController');
Route::get('ekspedisi.json', 'EkspedisiController@json');
...
```

NOTE: `I'm using Laravel 5.8, PostgreSQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, but i still don't know why it works, if someone can explain, please put your comment :), i change into :

***EkspedisiController.php***

```
$ekspedisi = Ekspedisi::join('clients', 'clients.client_id', '=' ,'ekspedisis.client_id')
                     ->join('organizations', 'organizations.org_id', '=', 'ekspedisis.org_id')
                     ->select('ekspedisis.*', 'clients.client_name', 'organizations.org_name') 
                     ->get();
```

Comment: How to if i want to add Filter in Where Look Like this 
if(blalalala ){
->leftJoin(blalalal)
}